# Missing AWS Codebuild Runtimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

A few days ago I set up a pipeline that works great using AWS pipelines.  When I set it up I was able to view/select multiple Runtimes.  Yesterday and today when I went into the console to set up one for a new environment the only option I get is

```
aws/codebuild/standard:1.0-1.8.0
```

[image: Here is a picture of what I can select]

I'm curious if I need to alter the account, If AWS is missing some of the images, Or am I going about this the wrong way to get other runtimes such as Python and Node like I did a few days ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new image "aws/codebuild/standard" has all supported runtimes in one image. Dockerfile can be viewed at https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/1.0/Dockerfile. This new image is based on Ubuntu 18.04, while the previous per runtime ones were based on Ubuntu 14.04, which is technically EOL now.